# Find value and Sum values from columns

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and I would appreciate your help in a writing a macro for the following issue:

I am working on a liquidity report and since vendors are paid in defined dates  I need to "move" all transactions on the specific date.

Practically, I need to identify a cell (based on the value of another cell) and sum there values from the range before and clear the cells with the original values.

[image: Excel worksheet]

Example: 
- CIT 1 (cell AA11) is the date when vendors are paid
- Values in range X10:Z10 have to be summed in AA10 and cleared from range X10:Z10

PS: both CIT and therefore the range to be "moved" on CIT date are not always the same. It depends on which calendar days CIT is defined.

Comment: is it always the same? Like CIT 1 is always on the spot where you want the procedure to begin?

Also are there always 3 values to sum up?

Comment: It is not always the same: both CIT can change date and the range of values to sum/clear can consist of more than 3.  I guess I need some sort of dynamic codee both to find CIT and identify range to be moved on CIT. Every value that falls in a date before CIT need to be moved on CIT

Comment: then it is up to you to decide what will be the dynamic rule to determine how many columns to sum and what to look for. That must take place before coding. Just think about the rule. The coding is never problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on this,

```
Sub Sum_and_Clear()
    Range("AA10")=Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("X10:Z10"))
    Range("X10:Z10").Clear
End Sub
```

This will scan the row 11 to find `CIT*` and sum the 3 previous columns and clear them :

```
Sub test_giovannicalamai()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, _
    LastCol As Integer, _
    RgToSum As Range, _
    CitCell As Range

Set Ws = ActiveSheet
With Ws
    LastCol = .Cells(.Columns.Count, 4).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For j = 9 To LastCol
        If LCase(Left(.Cells(11, j), 3)) <> "cit" Then
        Else
            Set CitCell = .Cells(11, j)
            Set RgToSum = .Range(CitCell.Offset(-1, -3), CitCell.Offset(-1, -1))
            CitCell.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(RgToSum)
            RgToSum.Clear
        End If
    Next j
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you R3uK but I think that your suggestion is too "rigid".See my comments above: I think I need some sort of dynamic formula

Comment: Ok give the edit a try (in a copy of your workbook, because a change done by code can't be undone).